# Squid cache + direct routing

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, squid

again here to ask for your help...

This time i need to setup a cluster of 2 squid caching proxies to speedup some apache servers.
The good thing is that there is no NAT involed so only direct routing.

Right now I'm able to divert the traffic for specific IP addresses using policy routing on juniper firewalls [the gateway] (if IP dst range within x.x.x.x-x.x.x.x and dest port = 80 then route it trough my squid IP but don't alter the packets itself).

But something that leaves me a bit of troubles is how should i intercept the traffic and alter it so that it's directly taken by the squid box instead of routed to the apache servers.
Obviously there is iptables here which I'm not really good at so if you can provide me a bit of help into setting up the rules i would thank you very much

Clearly what i want to achieve is just a transparent caching proxy for HTTP traffic which should speed up a range of IP addresses (multiple servers) using only public IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add iptables rules which catch the same traffic and redirect it to the Squid port on localhost. Something like this should do that:

```
iptables --table nat --append PREROUTING --destination <apache ip1>,<apache ip2> --protocol tcp --port 80 --jump DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:3128
```

The other option is to get the Juniper firewall to perform the DNAT instead of just altering the routing.

Comment: But doesn't destination NATting alter the packet in such way that it will reply with the squid IP address?

Comment: iptables will alter the response packets such that the source IP is the original destination (i.e. the apache server).